# SQL group by merge results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

how to run query select "sub" grouped by "cat" to return something like this:

SQL query:

```
select sub
from post
where cat = 1
group by id
```

to return something like:

```
3,4,9,14,33,22
```

table "post"

```
id      cat     sub
1        1       3,4,9,14
2        2       1,2
3        2       4,5
4        1       33,22
5        3       1,4
```

thanks,

Comment: I think you mean `where cat = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to store lists of things in character strings.  For one thing, your `id`s are integers, but the strings are characters.  More importantly, SQL has a great data structure for storing lists -- it is called a table.  You should be using a junction table.

But, sometimes you are stuck with the data you have.  In that case, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(sub)
from post
where cat = 1;
```

Comment: thanks, I update question, (yea, it's very bad but I requested to work in this situation)